# What is 'factored models'?

Tags: probability, distributions, structural-equation-modeling, expectation-maximization, bayesian-network

What is 'factored models'?

I've seen the term 'factored models' in paper 'The Bayesian Structural EM Algorithm'.
But I see it for the first time and it is hard to understand...

I tried searching it but cannot found.
What is 'factored models'?

Sorry for not writing in detail.
It is hard to write in detail because I don't know about it too much...

https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7373
https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1301/1301.7373.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a made-up term from this article. The definition appears immediately before Assumption 1.

(There's nothing hidden here - he's just making some assumption about the form of the distribution).

Informally, people often use "factored" to refer to models that can be written as a big product of simpler terms. The notation here is not really consistent across application areas - basically it depends on what the author is focusing on.